# Cannot Install anything on Kali Linux 2018

Tags: apt, software-installation, sudo, kali-linux

```
root@Kali:~# echo -e "deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib\ndeb http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list

root@Kali:~# apt-get update

Ign:1 h t t p : / / http . kali . org/kali sana InRelease                                     
Err:2 h t t p : / / http . kali . org/kali sana Release                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Ign:3 h t t p : / / http . kali . org/kali-security sana/updates InRelease
Err:4 h t t p : / / http . kali . org/kali-security sana/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Reading package lists... Done

E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali sana Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@Kali:~# apt-get update --fix-missing 
Ign:1 h t t p : / / http . kali . org/kali sana InRelease                                     
Ign:2 h t t p : / / http . kali . org/kali-security sana/updates InRelease                
Err:3 h t t p : / / http . kali . org/kali sana Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:4 h t t p : / / http . kali . org/kali-security sana/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'h t t p : / / http . kali . org/kali sana Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'h t t p : / / security . kali . org / kali-security sana/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

root@Kali:~# apt-get install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'tor' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: One rule, if you're gonna ask questions about Kali, then pretend it's not Kali you're using. They shutdown Kali questions for no reason. You can have no effort, but Kali is definitely gonna be closed.

Comment: @神秘德里克 Not true: if expert questions are asked on Kali, they do get attention, but Kali is the wrong distro for most people, which the duplicate points out.  Here there is not even a question asked, just a bunch of errors with the title being the sole background. **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: I got the answer, it was due to my sources List.

Answer (score 3):

Your sources.list should contain only the following line:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```